# FB - I cannot get into my application's page

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

I have created new FB application, but after I created it, I can't get into its page:

https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=205809329503822.

I see there only message

> "The page you requested was not found.".

I tried to add a new application, but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Newly created applications don't have application profile pages anymore.

See next blog post on developers blog:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/